Failed Deployment on Netlify
I have a React website deployed on Netlify, the website is live and I made some changes on my Github file but the changes are not reflecting because the deployment keeps failing when it gets to the build stage
I have searched for a possible solution, and changed the deployment settings based on solutions provided online to Build command: CI= npm run build but I still get the same error.
// error log
8:58:53 PM: Netlify Build                                                 
8:58:54 PM:   throw err;
8:58:54 PM:   ^
8:58:54 PM: Error: Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen'
8:58:54 PM: Require stack:
8:58:54 PM: - /opt/build/repo/node_modules/ajv- 
keywords/dist/definitions/typeof.js
8:58:54 PM: - /opt/build/repo/node_modules/ajv- 
keywords/dist/keywords/typeof.js
8:58:54 PM: - /opt/build/repo/node_modules/ajv- 
keywords/dist/keywords/index.js
8:58:54 PM: - /opt/build/repo/node_modules/ajv- 
keywords/dist/index.js
8:58:54 PM: - /opt/build/repo/node_modules/schema- 
utils/dist/validate.js
8:58:54 PM: - /opt/build/repo/node_modules/schema- 
utils/dist/index.js
8:58:54 PM: - /opt/build/repo/node_modules/mini-css-extract- 
plugin/dist/index.js
8:58:54 PM: - /opt/build/repo/node_modules/react- 
scripts/config/webpack.config.js
8:58:54 PM: - /opt/build/repo/node_modules/react- 
scripts/scripts/build.js
8:58:54 PM:     at Module._resolveFilename 
(node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1140:15)
8:58:54 PM:     at Module._load 
(node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:27)
8:58:54 PM:     at Module.require 
(node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
8:58:54 PM:     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18)
8:58:54 PM:     at Object.<anonymous> 
(/opt/build/repo/node_modules/ajv- 
keywords/dist/definitions/typeof.js:3:19)
8:58:54 PM:     at Module._compile 
(node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1364:14)
8:58:54 PM:     at Module._extensions..js 
(node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
8:58:54 PM:     at Module.load 
(node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)
8:58:54 PM:     at Module._load 
(node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:12)
8:58:54 PM:     at Module.require 
(node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19) {
8:58:54 PM:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
8:58:54 PM:   requireStack: [
8:58:54 PM:     '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/ajv- 
keywords/dist/definitions/typeof.js',
8:58:54 PM:     '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/ajv- 
keywords/dist/keywords/typeof.js',
8:58:54 PM:     '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/ajv- 
keywords/dist/keywords/index.js',
8:58:54 PM:     '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/ajv- 
keywords/dist/index.js',
8:58:54 PM:     '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/schema- 
utils/dist/validate.js',
8:58:54 PM:     '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/schema- 
utils/dist/index.js',
8:58:54 PM:     '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/mini-css-extract- 
plugin/dist/index.js',
8:58:54 PM:     '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/react- 
scripts/config/webpack.config.js',
8:58:54 PM:     '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/react- 
scripts/scripts/build.js'
8:58:54 PM:   ]
8:58:54 PM: }
8:58:54 PM: Node.js v18.20.4​
8:58:54 PM: "build.command" failed                                        
8:58:54 PM:   Error message
8:58:54 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: CI= npm run build 
(https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
8:58:54 PM: ​
8:58:54 PM:   Error location
8:58:54 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
8:58:54 PM:   CI= npm run build​
8:58:54 PM:   Resolved config
8:58:54 PM:   build:
8:58:54 PM:     command: CI= npm run build
8:58:54 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
8:58:54 PM:     environment:
8:58:54 PM:       - NPM_FLAGS
8:58:54 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/build
8:58:54 PM:     publishOrigin: ui
8:58:55 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script 
returned 
non-zero exit code: 2 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-2)
8:58:55 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script 
returned 
non-zero exit code: 2
8:58:55 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
8:58:55 PM: Finished processing build request in 45.693s


It's advisable to include your error or warning logs, so that it can be reviewed.

Deployment questions fit better on DevOps stack exchange. But there you're expected to provide a [mcve] and debugging details, too.

Have you debugged Error: Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen'?

Try to delete your node_module and run npm install if it will install the missing  module. Also, can you run the code locally?

Yes @beth, I can run the code on my local machine, and changes reflect locally too.

If the code runs locally then it is probably a problem with the deployment, try this line change the build command to this Build command: npm install --force && CI= npm run build

How do you install the dependencies in the CI? Do you install with npm ci? Do you install dev dependencies? I see Context production. That's strange. Why do you build in production environment? Sometime it also means installation without dev dependencies. Do you see errors in the installation step? Unrelated: Don't use CRA. It's deprecated for 2 years and contains security issues that won't be fixed anymore. It's a dead project.

Yes!!!! That fixed it. I have been on this all day. Kindly make this an answer so I can accept it.

@jabaa, the install is not done with npm ci there is a build & deployment settings section on Netlify where you can input the command, so when you click on deploy those commands will be executed.

@beth You can see in the logs that /opt/build/repo/node_modules/ajv-  keywords/dist/definitions/typeof.js was installed. That means, that an installation was run, but it didn't install all necessary packages. It installed  ajv-keywords but not ajv. npm install --force && CI= npm run build hides the actual problem. It's either an outdated package-lock.json, a wrong installation configuration or something else. Even worse, it could mean, that node_modules is added to the Git repository.

The issue is due to the missing module, it runs locally because the module is installed but not installed on Netlify.  Including "npm install" in the command build will allow the production to run npm install first before the build
Build command: npm install --force && CI= npm run build


Please fix the installation step. Don't add an additional installation step to the build step.
